# Scrape data that is shown once a button is clicked

Tags: python

I'm a web-scraping beginner who's only scraped non-interactive stuff until now. On the site I'm trying to scrape, some data like Rating and Last Updated, for each element is shown only when "More" button is pressed. I'm looking at what changes in "Inspect element" –

```
style="display: None;"
```

changes into

```
style="display: table-row;"
```

If I try to scrape just by the class name, everything I'm looking for seems to be sealed under a for loop

```
<tbody class="list-item" style="display: none;" v-for="(item, i) in items">
```

and I can't get my head around how to grab that hidden data.

The only code I could muster is the following:

```
import requests
import bs4
req = requests.get(f'https://myanimelist.net/animelist/kropiciel?status=7')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
soup_string = str(soup.select('.list-item'))
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the code you've written to date? If user interaction/JavaScript is required to render/retrieve the data you're after, your options are limited to browser emulation suites like Selenium or Puppeteer, as more rudimentary HTTP libraries and HTML parsers like `requests`/BeautifulSoup aren't capable of triggering/evaluating such code

Comment: I've provided the little I could write and got overwhelmed by the problem. From what I've seen, I think there is a function in .js that grabs the info about each element from a server, but I've little to no idea about JavaScript. >showMore:function(e){var t="anime"===p?e.anime_id:e.manga_id,n=l("#more-"+t);n.is(":visible")?n.hide():n.find(".more-content").find("table").exists()?n.show():l.post("/includes/ajax-no-auth.inc.php?t=6",{color:1,id:t,memId:d,type:p},(function(e){n.find(".more-content").html(e.html),n.show()}),"json")} looks like a jumble to me. I think I'll give Selenium a read